# physical constants with subscripts in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, physics

I have a little Problem. I have searched for quite a while but haven't found an answer (help, I'm a beginner).
I want to make my own Notebook for physical calculations in mathematica 9. The notebook should be easy to use and one should be able to get an overview quickly (reason I don't want to use quantity every single time). I want to display my equations just like in a Textbook. My problem are the subscripts which I need for the ElectronMass for example. They need to be a Symbol, because I want to protect those values. But it doesn't work. I can change m and get a different value for Electronmass. Here's my notebook:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]

Subscript[m, e] = Quantity["ElectronMass"];
Subscript[m, p] = Quantity["ProtonMass"];
Subscript[m, n] = Quantity["NeutronMass"];
Protect[Subscript[m, el], Subscript[m, p], Subscript[m, n]];
```

so far so good... but then this happens...

```
In[19]:= m = 5

Out[19]= 5

In[20]:= Subscript[m, e ]

Out[20]= Subscript[5, e]
```

instead I would want

```
In[20]:= Subscript[m, e ]

Out[20]= Subscript[m, e]
```

just treating Subscript[m, e] independently from anything which has to do with "m" or "e"
thanks for the help

Comment: Hi  @wikaa, I invite you have a look at the new(-ish) specialized Mathematica stackexchange site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ and open an account there too.

Answer (score 2):

An easy work around is simply to protect all symbols you want to use, so instead of

```
Protect[Subscript[m, el], Subscript[m, p], Subscript[m, n]];
```

You need write

```
Protect[m,el,n];
```

That way once you set the values

```
Subscript[m, n] = 2;
Subscript[m, el] = 4;
```

later when evaluating them you are guaranteed to be returned the correct values. As a quick note, you might like to redefine the subscript for some motive, such as

```
Subscript[a_, b_] := a[b]
```

Comment: Hi  Artur, I invite you have a look at the new(-ish) specialized Mathematica stackexchange site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ and open an account there too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Artur's method you could set `HoldAll` on `Subscript` which will prevent evaluation of these Symbols.  This should not be done lightly as it will affect *all* uses of `Subscript` but it may be exactly what you want if you desire this behavior to be general.

```
SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldAll]

m = 5; e = 3;

Subscript[m, e]
```

> ```
> (* Out= *) Quantity["ElectronMass"]
> ```

---

Dedicated StackExchange site:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, so far I think this is exactly what i need. Maybe you can point out some of the disadvantages this method has, i don't exactly understand what i would need subscripts for besides defining constants.

Comment: @wikaa `Subscript` is an undefined function, other than its formatting properties.  However, it can be used for many different things.  Especially if you rely on other people's code, or may do so in the future, and need to use both your code and theirs in the same `Context` you need to be sure that it isn't already being used for something that *requires* evaluation that will be prevented by `HoldAll`. (continued)

Comment: I'm not aware of any functionality in a default *Mathematica* session that will break with this setting, and in principle there should not be any as it is intended as a user-assignable function, but I also have not tried it extensively.  A word of warning: many people feel you should not use subscripted variables at all because of the difficulties they cause; see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/121) and the posts linked within.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent *Hold (your breath)* and *Protect (your precious variables)* answers you got so far, I rather suggest you stop and think for a moment.

Is this a limitation/quirk of MMA or rather a limitation of the logic/style of your paper/notebook?

After all: you go at great lengths to define m's with subscripts to indicate specific masses. Then why on earth do you want to define a quantity (constant, perhaps) just m without subscrpts?

Is it a mass? then give it a subscript to indicate what kind of mass it is.

Is it not a mass? Then call it something else. Use a longer - more descrptive - variable name, or *mm* if you have really run out of creativity.

In general do not confuse your readers with similar symbols having widely different meanings.

Also , I would not type

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

since this is way too general.
I would type

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["m", "_"]]]
```

which restricts the kind of physical objects with pretty subscripts.
Of course, you can always later add

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["q", "_"]]]
```

if you need to describe other subscripted quantities (say charges).,

Comment: well let's say i define: m = Quantity[1, "Meters"]; e= UnitConvert[Quantity["ElementaryCharge"] ]; Does this make sense? I just used m=5 to show, in a simple and quick way, that this doesn't work the way i want it to. when evaluating Subscript[m,e] i would get (* Out= *) Subscript[m,[Quantity["ElectronMass"]]. Hold works best for me.